# Angular 1 promise in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I've been going crazy trying to get something to work in Angular 1.3 that may not even be possible... but it seems like it should be. Basically, I'd like to write a service that returns only a calculated value, not a promise.

I have a service that makes an $http.get request and returns a promise. I'd like to call this from another service, get that data, manipulate it and return a value. I don't want to have to deal with .then once I've called my service. My reasoning is that I'd like to have a sharable function that I can call and receive an actual value so that I can use it as a condition for something like ng-show. Like I say, I'd write this function in the controller and use .then to assign a variable with the data from the promise, but I don't want to write that in every single controller I need this in.

Example:

```
app.factory('searchService', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    performSearch: function(searchString) {
      return $http.get('http://asdf.com/search/' + searchString);
    },
    getItemCount: function(itemName) {
      var _this = this;
      this.count = 0;

      this.performSearch(itemName).then(
        function successCallback(resp) {
          _this.count = resp.data.items.length;
        },
        function errorCallback() {
          // This section doesn't matter right now
        };

       return this.count;
    }
  };
}]);
```

So I'd like to just be able to call this from the controller and get back a "5" or something. Or even better, calling it from an ng-show like "ng-show="blahCtrl.getItemCount('item_search_string') == 0". Again, I have multiple controllers I may need this in, so I'd rather not duplicate functions all over the place just to extract that number I need.

This just doesn't work for me though... my return value is always whatever I initially set this.count to be. I've inserted a console.log a few places and have seen that (it seems) this.count is returned before the callback function can set its value. No matter what I do, I'm incapable of just returning a single value from this service and it's driving me crazy! What confuses me more is that if I were to do this code from inside the controller:

```
var _this = this;
searchService.performSearch('asdf').then(
  function(data) { _this.searchResults.data; }
);
```

It works just fine and I get my promise data right inside of the searchResults variable no problem. It just doesn't work that way inside of the service for some reason.

Hopefully this makes sense, I may have rambled a bit or been unclear. Any help would be greatly appreciated... I've spent about as much time researching this and using trial and error on my own as I can.

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at $object usage of Restangular very close to your wish...

Comment: from your requirements, looks like you intend performSearch to be a private function, so why return it.  Instead return {getItemCount: function(){....}}.  write function performSearch (){} just before the return {}.  this is an private function when you define it this way and not return it.  If you want the invoke performSearch, then having to use .then only makes sense semantically - "Call performSearch and THEN upon outcome --DO-- something.  It seems like you are stuck between what you want, code quality and syntaxes.

Answer (score 1):

One solution as i see.

Put this once in controller

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, searchService) {
   $scope.searchService = searchService;
   searchService.getItemCount();
});
```

and get in all view

```
{{ searchService.count }}
```

And i think, it's bad to make a request for each `ng-if`, `ng-show` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to use $q (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Your function is returning before the promise is fulfilled. Your getItemCount should look like this:

```
app.factory('searchService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    performSearch: function(searchString) {
      return $http.get('http://asdf.com/search/' + searchString);
    },
    getItemCount: function(itemName) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      this.performSearch(itemName).then(
        function successCallback(resp) {
          deferred.resolve(resp.data.items.length);
        },
        function errorCallback(err) {
          deferred.reject(err);
        };

       return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: This still returns a promise though right? When I try this, all I get is {} returned. When I just return deferred I see it's {"promise":{}}

Comment: This returns a promise that will be resolved to `resp.data.items.length`. If you want to console.log the amount of items you should put that statement in the .then function. For instance: `getItemCount('myitem').then(function(response) { console.log(response) } );`

Comment: Yeah, I've done that. But the whole point here is to just return an integer when I run this service function, not ANOTHER promise that I have to deal with again. Is there no way to do this? I mean, if I add a .then() to my performSearch() function and resolve the promise there, then when I'm in getItemCount shouldn't I just be able to say performSearch().then() and assign the data from the resolved promise to a variable that I can return? But it never works that way... It always skips over my performSearch().then and returns without waiting.

Comment: Just so you know, ng-show accepts a promise as a value so you can do `"ng-show=myCtrl.getItemCount('myitem')>0"`. The only way to avoid the promise is to either set it in the controller calling performSearch.then() or to convert this factory to a service and have a this.count property which gets set in the performSearch method.